# How to use gem cryptocompare in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a newbie to Ruby. I am building a crypto news site. I want to use gem cryptocompare (https://github.com/alexanderdavidpan/cryptocompare) which uses cryptocompare's API but I am lost.

I need help.

Thanks in advance.

The documentation uses module like functions for example:

**gem screenshot**

[image]

My controller is like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :like]
#   before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]    

    def index

        @posts = Post.of_followed_users(current_user.following).order('created_at DESC').page params[:page]
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').page params[:page]
        @coinlists = Cryptocompare::CoinList.all

        @my_coins = []
        @coinlists.each {|coin| @my_coins.push(coin) }

    end
```

And my view like this:

```
<% @my_coins.each {|coin| puts coin } %>
```

Problem is that nothing happens; don't know what to do to fix this. When I use this other iteration, it throws error:

Method

```
def index

@coinlists = Cryptocompare::CoinList.all      
@my_coins = []

        @coinlists.each do |coin|
            coin["Name"]
            coin["Symbol"]
            @my_coins.push(coin)
        end
end
```

in my View

```
<% @my_coins.each_with_index do |coin, index| %>

         <%= coin["Name"] %>
         <%= coin["Symbol"] %>

<% end %>
```

See the **error** below:

> TypeError in PostsController#index no implicit conversion of String
>   into Integer

Comment: Usually, when someone writes in all caps, it is supposed to be interpreted as shouting. Are you shouting at us? If not, please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51509728/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing the wrong data in your `@coinlists`. According to the gem's documentation, what you should be storing is actually the `"Data"` key.

In your controller action, it should be like this:

```
def index
  ...
  @coinlists = Cryptocompare::CoinList.all["Data"]
end
```

In your view:

```
<% @coinlists.values.each do |coin| %>
  <%= coin["Name"] %>
  <%= coin["Symbol"] %>
<% end %>
```

You should learn more about how [hashes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html) work in Rails. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may prefer [Hash#each_value](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_value) -- it avoids unnecessary Array allocation incurred by `@coinlists.values.each { |coin| ... }`.

You might refer to these generally useful [performance optimisations](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby#hasheach_key-instead-of-hashkeyseach-code).